# Importing my custom class and calling it's method?

Tags: android, class, import

I have created a custom class for my Android project called "Sounds" I want to be able to call it from my activity. The contents of my class are as follows:

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.SoundPool;

public class Sounds {

private static boolean sound = true;

private static final int FLIP_SOUND = 1;

private static Context context;
private static SoundPool soundPool;
private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundPoolMap;

public static void initSounds() {
    soundPoolMap.put(FLIP_SOUND, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.flip, 1));
}

public static void playFlip() {
        soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(FLIP_SOUND), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
}

public static void setSound(Boolean onOff) {
    sound = onOff;
}
}
```

In my main Activity class I have tried importing the class, creating an instance of it but I guess I'm just not understanding how it's done. Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Comment: My how things change in a few short years. It seems this question is still popular and that people are having similar issues, new Android developers I imagine, as I was at the time. I'm looking at this wondering how I ever expected it to work. The obvious thing in the code above is that context is never initialised (nor are any of hte fields in fact), the class either requires a constructor (and non-static fields), or the necessary parameters (such as the context, soundpool and soundPoolMap) you see here passed directly to the static methods. Otherwise, they will always be null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edited: From your `Activity` class:

```
private Sounds s;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        s = new Sounds(this);
        s.initSounds();
}
```

You might also send the context with the constructor to your custom class.

Remove the static variables and methods:

```
public class Sounds {

private boolean sound = true;

private int FLIP_SOUND = 1;

private Context context;
private SoundPool soundPool;
private HashMap soundPoolMap;

public Sounds(Context context){
   this.context = context;
   soundPoolMap = new HashMap();
   soundPool = new SoundPool(0, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
}

public void initSounds() {
   soundPoolMap.put(FLIP_SOUND, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.flip, 1));
}

public void playFlip() {
    soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(FLIP_SOUND), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
}

public void setSound(Boolean onOff) {
   sound = onOff;
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried everything specified here with my last resort being the "static"'s being the cause, after the suggestion up top I removed them where told and the program still forcecloses as soon as the activity attempts to call s.initSounds(); I'm assuming the problem is the context, as it gave me problems before. Can you suggest how I should pass the context correctly?

Comment: Thanks, I have done this but the program still forcecloses when i call initSounds(); If I comment this out it works fine. I'm not sure if it's relevent, but the activity that I'm working in is called from a previous (parent?) activity by an intent...

Comment: @Hamid: Start DDMS and look for an error message when this force close takes place.

Comment: I have been using logcat to do the same thing, it shows: FATAL EXCEPTION main, RuntimeException "Unable to start Activity" com.mypackage.MyActivity, followed by java.lang.NullPointerException. Caused by NullPointerException at com.mypackage.Sounds.initSounds(Sounds.java:21) at com.mypackage.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:42)....at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)

Comment: That sounds strange... I'm not familiar with the `SoundPool` class, but are you sure that this line is correct: `soundPoolMap.put(FLIP_SOUND, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.flip, 1));`?

Comment: Seems pretty obvious to me at this point, you never initialized `soundPoolMap`, so it's a null reference. Make sure to change it to `private HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();` (I think)

Comment: @Andrew: Initializing made no difference. @Charlie: That line is the problem, commenting it out stops the forceclose, as far as I know though it is correct. Again, I believe the context might be the problem as it gave me problems before and that's why I shifted all this into a seperate class.

Comment: @Hamid: You have to initialize it like Andrew wrote earlier. Try change my updated code.

Comment: Well, it probably did make a difference, it likely moved the NullPointerException from soundPoolMap to something else. Are you initializing `soundPool` too, like Charlie's example? Are you passing the reference to `context` too?

Comment: That worked perfectly, I had already tried this before but it just force closed, it seems your parameters to the new soundPool instance were the key difference, I had SoundPool(5,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,1); the first number apparently is how many simultanious stream are allowed, I had it at 5, why does zero work? and the last 0 is the priority, the API reference says it should be kept at 1 for future comptability because it isnt yet implemented.

Comment: Thank you both Andrew and Charlie for your fast and conclusive help that has solved the problem. Now I need to go take something for my headache before I continue. Thanks again.

Comment: @Hamid: Glad we could help you!

Answer (score 2):

I've got also issues on this peculiar usage of classes. I'm a newbie in Android and even in the usage of classes and i am studing the WebInterface.

The Shane Oliver's solution worked for me using the standard class variables.

In the Activity class :

```
Private JavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface;
myJavaScriptInterface.Toastshow("Hi EveryOne");
```

or even :

```
JavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
```

As for the class JavaScriptInterface :

```
 public class JavaScriptInterface {

    Context myContext;

    //Instanciar o interface e definir o conteudo 
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        myContext = c;
    }


    public void Toastshow(String toast_msg)
    {


        Toast.makeText(myContext, toast_msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Sounds s = new Sounds();
s.initSounds();
s.playFlip();
s.setSound(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made all the methods of the class static. If you want to use them as-is, call them with `Sounds.initSound()` and so on. However, since you have class variables, static methods and variables don't look appropriate. Remove `static` from your members (except from `FLIP_SOUND`) and then try creating an instance of the class and calling methods like normal.