# Using a separate java files methods

Tags: java, android, import

This question is about Android, although i dont think that this is android-specific.

I have a project that i want to use two files with: MainActivity.java and filetools.java . I have three methods in filetools.java, read, write and append.
I want to be able to do something like this in my MainActivity:

`filetools.write("/sdcard/file.txt", "something");`

The code for MainActivity is just the package, imports, the class, and onCreate.

The code for filetools:

```
package com.tylerr147.FileRW;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class filetools
{
      public String read(String fName){
       try{
          File mFile = new File(fName);
          String content = new Scanner(mFile).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
      return content;
    }catch(Exception e) {
      return "There was an error retrieving your file. The proccess returned this error:\n"+e.toString();
    }

  }

  public boolean write(String loc, String stuff) {
    File mfile = new File(loc);
    try {
      mfile.createNewFile();
      FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(mfile);
      OutputStreamWriter f2 = new OutputStreamWriter(f);
      f2.append(stuff);
      f2.close();
      f.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  public void append(String filename,     String content) {
    write(filename, read(filename)+content);
  }
}
```

Another thing i would like to be able to do is to have a completely different app by the package com.app.importer

how could i do something like

```
import com.app.importer;

importerAppsMethod();
```

I have found a few posts on stackoverflow, but they do not help.

[Importing my custom class and calling it's method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907128/importing-my-custom-class-and-calling-its-method)

There are a few more, and i have searched and can not find anything that works for me. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is the MainActivity class in a different package to filetools? Is this just a question of classes from different packages using each other?

Comment: No, they are in the same package. I did ask a little side question about using different packages though.

Comment: To do something like `filetools.write("/sdcard/file.txt", "something");` - you need to declare the `write` method as static. For example: `public static boolean write(String loc, String stuff)`. You may have to do the same for all other methods if you want similar behavior. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @ishmaelMalitla yes that works, could you put that in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am putting @ishmaelMakitla comment intocan answer.

To do something like filetools.write("/sdcard/file.txt", "something"); - you need to declare the write method as static. For example: public static boolean write(String loc, String stuff). You may have to do the same for all other methods if you want similar behavior. Is this what you are looking for?